# Why didn't the transaction go through? What is the reason?Transaction has been reverted by the EVM

Tags: erc-20

Why didn't the transaction go through? What is the reason?Transaction has been reverted by the EVM
0xc3519e53c2502987698055bc9ce33d8e439d27afe16b90bd4ad77c0c1c674ff3

Answer (score 2):

The transaction ran out of gas. The gas limit was set to 22000, which is not enough for ERC20 transfers. In most cases those will consume 50-100k gas.